# How to find the limit of cos(2x)/x as x approaches zero

Tags: limits

Basicly the title. I know it's easy but I can't figure it out. [Edit] Not a duplicate has a 2x instead of x.

Comment: what is $\cos 0?$

Comment: It is when $x\to 0^+$? (i.e., only by positive values?) As asked, the limit does not exist.

Comment: "Basically the title" is not a question. Please make your question's body self contained. If your entire question fits into the title, it is *not* a good question.

Comment: If its a short question then it can fit into the title. Doesn't mean its a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

As x approaches 0 Cos(x) approaches 1 so we can in a sense think of 1/x. As x goes to 0 from the positive side 1/x approaches infinity. But when x goes to 0 from the negative side 1/x goes instead to negative infinity. This means that the limit as x goes to 0 for Cos(x)/x is undefined as the left and right limits do not agree.